# How can I move a cube between other targets in different ways between each one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementSpeedController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] targets;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,
        targets[0].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position == targets[0].position)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
            targets[1].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (transform.position == targets[1].position)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
            targets[2].position, ref velocity, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The script is attached to a cube the cube should move between 3 other cubes each cube in another positions. and I want that the transform will move to the first target using lerp then movetowards and then to the last cube using smoothdamp to show all the movements.

The problem is how to do it without manually type each target index 0,1,2 ? and how to move it between them because now this is true :

```
transform.position == targets[0].position
```

but it's not moving to the next cube.

Tried this :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementSpeedController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] targets;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    private int targetIndex = 0;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var targetPosition = targets[targetIndex];

        if (targetIndex == 0)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,
            targetPosition.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if(transform.position == targetPosition.position)
        {
            targetIndex++;

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
            targets[1].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a variable for `targetIndex`, initialize it to zero, and each time you reach the target increase that index.  Use that index in your targets array.  `targetPosition = targets[targetIndex];`  You can also use that index to figure out which movement type you need to use.  `if (targetIndex == 0) // do lerp` or in a switch case

Comment: @hijinxbassist Can you show me how to do it? I  updated my question with what I did I tried to change the Update to do it but not sure how to continue.

Comment: You are pretty close there with the second try, but there are a few things to consider.  1) When using Lerp, you should maintain a constant value for the from and to positions.  Before starting the lerp you want to cache the position of the transform so that it does not change.  It also need to go from 0 to 1, I generally use a coroutine to accomplish this, but the same could be done in update using a class variable for t.  2) comparing two position to be exact is generally a bad idea, as floating point precision could cause this condition to never be true.  There is a way to use epsilon value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable for targetIndex, initialize it to zero, and each time you reach the target increase that index. Use that index in your targets array.

```
targetPosition = targets[targetIndex];
```

You can also use that index to figure out which movement type you need to use.

```
if (targetIndex == 0) // do lerp or in a switch case
```

Here is an example.

```
private Vector3 startingPosition = Vector3.zero;
private int targetIndex = 0;
private float lerpT = 0;

void Start()
{
    targetIndex = -1;
    SetNextTarget();
}
void Update()
{
    switch (targetIndex)
    {
        case 0: UpdateLerp(); break;
        case 1: UpdateMoveTowards(); break;
        case 2: UpdateSmoothDamp(); break;
    }
}
void UpdateLerp()
{
    lerpT += Time.deltaTime * speed;

    if (lerpT > 1)
        lerpT = 1;

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startingPosition, target, lerpT);
    
    if (lerpT == 1)
    {
        SetNextTarget();
    }
}
void UpdateMoveTowards()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
    {
        SetNextTarget();
    }
}
void UpdateSmoothDamp()
{
    // Using the examples, fill in this one with the smooth damp version of movement
}
void SetNextTarget()
{
    targetIndex++;
    target = targets[targetIndex];
    startingPosition = transform.position;
}
```